# rails 4 asset pipeline production fingerprint

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, fingerprinting

i have an asset pipeline problem in rails 4. 
i have a directory in `testapp/public/assets/`  which has all hashed or fingerprinted css and javascripts `bootstrap.min-58853fb115aba672ce98597de33da61b.js OR animate-d81627498b7ff4acf1a1964da02db789.css` however in browser i see not hashed css and javascripts like `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">`
 i need to request the hashed files in my public/assets/

i have landing controller and one method
views/landing/one.html.erb

```
<%= render "shared/headmeta" %>
<%= render "shared/headcss"%>
<%= render "shared/headscript"%>
<%= render "shared/header"%>

<h1>Landing#one</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/landing/new.html.erb</p>


<%= render "shared/footer"%>
<%= render "shared/jscript"%
```

>

css manifest in landing.scss

```
/* ...
 *= require animate
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require default
 *= require style
 *= require overwrite
*/
```

headcss partial is :

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min",  media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>

    <!-- Overwrite bootstrap style -->

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "overwrite", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>

    <!-- Animate css -->

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "animate", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>

    <!-- Heading font -->

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

    <!-- General font -->
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans", media: "all" ,"data-turbolinks-track" => true%>

    <!-- Font icons -->

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "simple-line-icons", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

    <!-- Flexslider -->
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "flexslider", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>


    <!-- Theme skin -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "default", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gem devise

gem 'devise'


#sprockets is a rack-based asset packaging system that concatenates and serves Js,coffescript,css,LESS
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.12.3'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use yui as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'yui-compressor', '~> 0.12.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

***production.rb***

```
 Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
   config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

config/application.rb

```
 require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

    require 'rails/all'
    require "sprockets/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Marketpersona
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.assets.enabled = true

  end
end
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

Rails.application.config.assets.compress = true

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added
#Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
 # if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
  #  full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
   # app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    #if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
     #Rails. logger.info "including asset: " + full_path
      #true
    #else
     # Rails.logger.info "excluding asset: " + full_path
     # false
    #end
  #else
   # false
  #end
#end
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

public/assets output of some files

```
/public/assets# ls
animate-d2e7ae01911a05d8ce767b98def4ae3a.css                         jquery.smooth-scroll-5f54331165eef2a11b63f6d615d4556e.js.gz
animate-d2e7ae01911a05d8ce767b98def4ae3a.css.gz                      jquery.ui.totop-d23c655a6d2cb2716708132fbd150f5e.js
animate-d81627498b7ff4acf1a1964da02db789.css                         jquery.ui.totop-d23c655a6d2cb2716708132fbd150f5e.js.gz
animate-d81627498b7ff4acf1a1964da02db789.css.gz                      jquery.ui.totop-d5647d1f3ae94dc679d5767720d0ab73.js
application-88198fbec2cb093a4a5545b36197d203.js                      jquery.ui.totop-d5647d1f3ae94dc679d5767720d0ab73.js.gz
application-88198fbec2cb093a4a5545b36197d203.js.gz                   jquery_ujs-0b8f09cf5aec4ba1be1abd9f915c77e2.js
application-9ebac1bd19f3ba981afd79fd2c5f2037.css                     jquery_ujs-0b8f09cf5aec4ba1be1abd9f915c77e2.js.gz
application-9ebac1bd19f3ba981afd79fd2c5f2037.css.gz                  landing-307af29ac27a030829bb53a3718d3987.js
application-a6b3011ab79b9f60d493732939ce4f50.css                     landing-307af29ac27a030829bb53a3718d3987.js.gz
application-a6b3011ab79b9f60d493732939ce4f50.css.gz                  landing-7c3fe69fe5644297d4d87fdcc4b915d4.css
application-aceb45182f1f0486e0e79c02dea65c4e.css                     landing-7c3fe69fe5644297d4d87fdcc4b915d4.css.gz
application-aceb45182f1f0486e0e79c02dea65c4e.css.gz                  landing-8f6eecd1178ef85964369ec66d33c4f1.js
application-d012cec9935d5b05e1b812ccc6f3cf6d.css                     landing-8f6eecd1178ef85964369ec66d33c4f1.js.gz
application-d012cec9935d5b05e1b812ccc6f3cf6d.css.gz                  landing-9b1e28a2786f16d823f619cdc65d8a40.css
application-e038cd04ae9494b6950481cfc5d4d749.css                     landing-9b1e28a2786f16d823f619cdc65d8a40.css.gz
application-e038cd04ae9494b6950481cfc5d4d749.css.gz                  landing-a7374c322246655f8a4a6d05689e50ae.css
application-e1d3507ada82fdd954d492f952b28619.js                      landing-a7374c322246655f8a4a6d05689e50ae.css.gz
application-e1d3507ada82fdd954d492f952b28619.js.gz                   landing-d728d395d4bd4966f84f4acdd1d6691c.css
bootstrap.min-58853fb115aba672ce98597de33da61b.js                    landing-d728d395d4bd4966f84f4acdd1d6691c.css.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 9 stylesheets you are including in one page/app? Why not compile them into one using a manifest?

I really am not sure what is going on here... So you are not getting the compiled files in your production environment?

I may be misreading your question, but are you creating your own css manifest files other than application.css, for example assets/stylesheets/shared/? Then in your production.rb (environment) file you need to tell Rails to compile them:

```
AppName::Application.configure do

# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
config.assets.precompile += ['shared/filename.css', 'shared2/filename2.css']

end
```

Comment: Hello i add stylesheet and js link tag to my /layouts/application.html.erb but browser request different css file comparing to css files in my public/assets/ 
<title>We create persona for you | </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-a6b3011ab79b9f60d493732939ce4f50.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/application-88198fbec2cb093a4a5545b36197d203.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
</head>

Answer (score 0):

Run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` then add, commit and deploy your changes to production.